# how to update existing model with new + existing value in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to add the new score in the existing record,
else I want to insert the new values

I tried to do it in single statement as mentioned below

```
Score.objects.update_or_create(id='1',number='1',defaults=
{'points':F('points')+45)})
```

It is working fine for existing record but giving error for new record.

F('points') might be the reason 
Please suggest any alternative.

This is my `Score` model:

```
from django.db import models

class Score(models.Model):

    id=models.IntegerField()
    number=models.IntegerField()
    points=models.FloatField()

    class Meta: 
        db_table = "Score"
```

Comment: Show your Score model please.

Comment: from django.db import models

class Score(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "Score"
    id=models.IntegerField()
    number=models.IntegerField()
    points=models.FloatField()
this is my Score model

Comment: Try giving a default value for point -> points=models.FloatField(default=0)

Comment: giving error :"float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ExpressionNode' "
F('points') might be giving None, thus not able to convert none to float